# Does the main title theme from JAG have a name?

Tags: soundtrack, jag

I'm wondering that on the pilot soundtrack of [*JAG*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112022/) the main theme is segued into from "Engage and Destroy", but I don't think it's part of the same track. Does the title actually have a name, or just "Theme from JAG"?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to have a name. It seems to be listed as **Theme from JAG** by **Bruce Broughton** in most sites. For examples:

1. [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/main-theme-from-jag-by-bruce/id380839011)
2. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Main-Theme-JAG-Bruce-Broughton/dp/B003UQGJO2)